# dropzone not sending object correctly as params

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have a from and a `dropzone`, when user clicks on the add button if the form is completed the data is sent over `xhr` using `dropzone` options.

**html:**

```
<div id="fp_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <label class="label-control"><%= t :restaurant %></label>
      <span class="fa fa-star mandatory"></span>
      <select class="form-control fpInput restaurant"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <label class="label-control"><%= t :vendor %></label>
      <span class="fa fa-star mandatory"></span>
      <select class="form-control fpInput vendor"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <label class="label-control"><%= t :meal %></label>
      <span class="fa fa-star mandatory"></span>
      <select class="form-control fpInput meal"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <label class="label-control"><%= t :food %></label>
      <span class="fa fa-star mandatory"></span>
      <select class="form-control fpInput" id="foodLS"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <label class="label-control"><%= t :fa_food_material %></label>
      <span class="fa fa-star mandatory"></span>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control fpInput" id="fa_material"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <label class="label-control"><%= t :en_food_material %></label>
      <span class="fa fa-star mandatory"></span>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control fpInput" id="en_material"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <div class="dropzone" id="foodDZ">
        <div class="dz-message">
          <%= t :uploadFoodProfileImg %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="create_fp"><%= t :add %></button>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
var dropzone,
  selectedDpId = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
  Dropzone.options.foodDZ = {
    url: '/' + lang_code + '/admin/food_profiles',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    paramName: 'picture',
    params: {},
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
    init: function() {
      dropzone = this;
      this.on("success", function(file) {
        Command: toastr["success"](success)
      })
      this.on("error", function(file) {
        Command: toastr["error"](error)
      })
      this.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
        dropzone.removeAllFiles();
      });
    }
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#create_fp', function() {
  var foodValue = $('#foodLS').val();
  var faMaterialValue = $('#fa_material').val();
  var enMaterialValue = $('#en_material').val();
  if (selectedDpId.toString().length > 0 && foodValue.length > 0 && faMaterialValue.length > 0 && enMaterialValue.length > 0) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.delivery_place_id = selectedDpId;
    obj.food_id = foodValue;
    obj.material_en = faMaterialValue;
    obj.material_fa = enMaterialValue;
    dropzone.options.params.food_profile = obj;
    dropzone.processQueue();
  } else {
    Command: toastr['warning'](complete_form);
  }
})
```

selectedDpId and complete_form variables are defined somewhere else. I used dropzone in click event (not in params option and not in sending event in init) since when dropzone is initiated it takes form attributes as empty (they only work with static data not dynamic ones) and I can not change the value when user completes the form but in this way it works.

**My problem** is that I want to send my forms data in food_profile object and even if I could send my picture in food_profile object too that would be great! but when I try to do so like above, in browser console I get Content-Disposition: form-data; name=food_profile [object Object] and not the actual data! I even tried to send obj as** `JSON.stringify(obj)` **it sends data as string and in backend side the parameters are not accepted and only objects are accepted.

Your help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a good solution for this dilemma (apparently sending an object as a value in params doesn't work great), I decided to move around this and change my backend api, I only use dropzone to upload photos then I save the id of the image in success response and when user completes the form, I send the picture id along with it, and in backend side the picture is bind to the specific form.
Hope it's useful for everyone having this problem.